# StartAsync() raises error System.IO.FileNotFoundException for downloading

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I am trying a Background Downloader for Windows 8.1. This is the `HandleDownloadAsync()` which I got from the Background Downloader sample.

It started getting a `FileNotFound Exception` at
`await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);`

It was working a few days back and I haven't changed the code. All the variables are assigned the correct values too.

What is wrong?

```
async void HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
{
    activeDownloads.Add(download);
    try
    {
        Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
        if (start)
        {
            await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
        }
        else
        {
            await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        activeDownloads.Remove(download);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it was working before, the `FileNotFoundException` means exactly what it says.  Check to make sure that the file you are trying to download exists in the location you are expecting it.

Comment: Preceeding this method, I have a method that creates the file and during runtime, I can see that file on my computer and even after when I stop debugging the file exists. The link that I am downloading from works fine too.

Comment: @dubstylee isn't wrong. Double, triple, quadruple check that the file definitely exists, get the file path and try navigating to it. Make sure are running the preceding method before you run this one. It's difficult to argue with a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I have checked this many times. I even set a breakpoint at the beginning of the program and stepped through each line and it works like its supposed too. The preceeding method works,the file gets created where I want it too, but still this FileNotFound Exception

Comment: Is the method which creates the file also asynchronous?  If so, make sure it is being awaited as well.  Another thing to check is that the file name is the same file name you are passing to the `DownloadOperation`.  Either the file is not there when it is supposed to be, or you are looking for the wrong file.

Comment: If the framework is thrown a `FileNotFoundException`, _then the file wasn't found_. Period. It's understandable that you may not understand why the file isn't found; after all, most bugs involve mistaken assumptions on the part of the coder. But you need to debug this so that you know exactly which file the exception is complaining about and track down why it's not visible to the code throwing the exception. In any case, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there's nothing anyone else can do to explain the exception.

Comment: thanks guys i will look at my code once again very thoroughly and come back here if I find anything else.